# Sinatra app on heroku gives 400 BAD_REQUEST errors with GET and query parameters

Tags: ruby, http, heroku, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra app that is supposed to receive GET requests that use query parameters, and take those parameters and dump them into a txt file.

When I test it locally using telnet - everything is great. I get 200 responses. The second I put it all up on heroku, no dice. 400 BAD_REQUESTS for everything. When I use a browser, everything is fine. I just can't send using telnet (or my arduino, which is what i'll be using).

Live site: 
http://weathervane.herokuapp.com/

Sample query string: 
`/sensor?temp=100&hum=200`

Also, in addition to the HTTP errors, it looks like the second parameter (hum) is getting cut off as well: 
http://cl.ly/image/3P46382p0D0v

Here's the index route

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

And here's the /sensor route.

```
get '/sensor' do

  File.open 'temp_data.txt', 'w' do |f|
    f.write params[:temp]
  end

  File.open 'hum_data.txt', 'w' do |f|
    f.write params[:hum]
  end

  "OK, Temp: #{params[:temp]} & Hum: #{params[:hum]}" 

end
```

Again, this all works locally...am I just missing a step in my heroku setup?

UPDATE: Here are the telnet print outs for when I try to get the index and the sensor route. It was just because I wasn't adding the host: header in the request.

Index with no host in header.

```
telnet weathervane.herokuapp.com 80
Trying 50.17.239.217...
Connected to us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Index with host in header. (looks like it did the trick!)

```
telnet weathervane.herokuapp.com 80
Trying 23.23.214.121...
Connected to us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: weathervane.herokuapp.com  

HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 03 Jun 2014 00:17:03 GMT
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 901
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Compost Monitor - aka "weathervane"</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Hi there!</h1>

    <div class="data">
      <div class="dataTitle">Time (at server):</div>
      <div id="timeDisplay">Getting time....</div>
    </div>

    <div class="data">
      <div class="dataTitle">Pile Tempurature:</div>
      <div id="tempDisplay">Getting temperature...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="data">
      <div class="dataTitle">Pile Humidity:</div>
      <div id="humDisplay">Getting humidity...</div>
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
      $("#timeDisplay").load("/time");
      $("#tempDisplay").load("/sensor/temp");
      $("#humDisplay").load("/sensor/hum");
    }, 5000);
  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's the /sensor route with no host header.

```
telnet weathervane.herokuapp.com 80
Trying 54.225.145.230...
Connected to us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /sensor?temp=100&hum=200 
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Here's the /sensor route with a host header. Look at the lovely 200 ok status. :)

```
telnet weathervane.herokuapp.com 80
Trying 54.225.77.87...
Connected to us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /sensor?temp=100&hum=200 HTTP/1.1
Host: weathervane.herokuapp.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 03 Jun 2014 00:20:48 GMT
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 24
Connection: keep-alive

OK, Temp: 100 & Hum: 200
```

Comment: It works okay for me. Paste in the results of your telnet session so we can see what’s going on. A few things to consider: (1) the `&` character means “run in background” in many shells, you might need to quote the request line depending on what you’re doing; (2) you’ll need a `Host:` header as part of your HTTP request, otherwise Heroku won’t know the request is for your app; (3) (not directly related to your current problem) Heroku uses an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), so you can’t really write files there safely.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll edit the question with telnet responses. I'll try adding in a host and see if that helps at all. Totally understand the ephemeral issue. The txt isn't a long term solution. Eventually I'll learn how to make a db for this. :)

Comment: That did the trick. It literally just needed the host header. FML. Thank you @matt I was going insane.